# href and anchor not detected by recorder in automation(coded ui test)

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

i trying to create coded ui test for my web application but while recording i m clicking on navigation which is `<ul><li>` and `<a href>` structure it is recorded properly but while running it is giving trouble and not working can you guess what is reason behind or do i need to work on some new things with my html control in my code or in search criteria which is auto generated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is insufficient detail in your question to even attempt an answer. Asking us to "guess" an answer is a waste of your time and ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the studio with all update it resolve the error. it will right dom element i solved the problem